# Use the Farkas Lemma to show the face correspondence of an unbounded pointed polyhedron P

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry

Use the Farkas Lemma to show that for every unbounded pointed polyhedron P there is an inequality $a^Tx \leq 1$ such that:
$$P' = \{x \in P: a^Tx \leq 1 \}$$
is a polytope with a facet $F′ = {x ∈ P : a^Tx = 1}$, such that k-dimensional faces of F′ correspond to k + 1-dimensional faces of P and k-dimensional faces of P′ that are not faces of F′ are in bijection with the k-dimensional faces of P.

Comment: This is a bare homework problem with no evidence of effort on your part. Such questions tend to attract downvotes and are likely to be closed. Please edit the question to show what you've attempted and explain where you are stuck. We are desirous of helping you improve your understanding of math, but do not want to just do the math for you.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Hi, I understand. I just don't know how to formulate the question in an easier way to induce people to help. My struggle is with the definition of face correspondence in the polytope. I have looked up the textbook but I still can't understand and find a hint anywhere. Can you give me some hints so that I can approach this problem? I'm just really confused and struggling.

Comment: "My struggle is with the definition of face correspondence in the polytope. I have looked up the textbook but I still can't understand and find a hint anywhere. " seems an adequate explanation of where you are stuck. The correspondence here is that each $k$-dimensional face of $F'$ is the intersection of $a^Tx = 1$ with some $k+1$ dimensional face of $P'$. As for the other "bijection", it is given by equality: each $k$-dimensional face of $P$ is a $k$-dimensional face of $P'$ but not of $F'$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair. Thanks. I was wondering why we have a $k$ dimensional face here since it is not given. Maybe we project them on somewhere? Or do we analyze the dimensionality by analyzing its rank? I understand that a face has the form of $c^Tx = \delta$ where $x: a^Tx \leq 1$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simplest non-trivial case of $P$: an angle in the plane.
[image]

The polytope $P$ has

- $2$-face the interior of the angle $\angle QSR$,
- $1$-faces $\vec{SQ}$ and $\vec{SR}$, and
- $0$-face the point $S$.

Choose $a^Tx = 1$ to be the red line, with $a$ chosen so $a^Tx < 1$ is the left half-plane. Then $P'$ has

- $2$-face the interior of the triangle $\triangle QSR$,
- $1$-faces $\overline{SQ}, \overline{SR}, \overline{QR}$
- $0$-faces the points $S, Q, R$.

$F'$ consists of

- $1$-face $\overline{QR}$ and
- $0$-faces the points $Q, R$.

So the two $0$-faces $Q, R$ correspond to the two $1$-faces $\overline{SQ}, \overline{SR}$ of $P'$, respectively, being the intersection of those two faces with $a^Tx = 1$. Note that $Q$ are $R$ are also $0$-faces of $P'$.

Meanwhile, the other $0$-face of $P'$ is the point $S$, which is also the sole $0$-face of the polytope $P$, which is the bijection they are referring to.

If you still don't see how to proceed, it may help to consider the case of $P$ being a $3$-dimensional polytope, with $a^Tx = 1$ being a plane instead of a line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will think about this more carefully.